# How to create a channel in a specific category?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a `Discord.js` bot. I want to create a function that triggers once you join a specific channel. When triggered, the bot will create a channel with your username in a specific category. The channel gets created successfully, but I didn't find any way to create it in the category I want by pointing its id.

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (_oldState, newState) => {
 try {
  let newUserChannel = newState.channelID;
  const channelhubID = '758361123316826124';
  const channel = newState.channel;
  if (newUserChannel == channelhubID) {
   const guild = channel.guild;
   const joinedUsername = newState.member.user.username;
   guild.channels.create(`${joinedUsername}`, { type: 'voice' });
  } else if (newUserChannel == undefined) {
  }
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
});
```

I don't get an error from this, but when I try to execute the `setParent` method, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options for [`GuildChannelManager.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) is the `parent` property.

```js
guild.channels.create(joinedUsername, {
 type: 'voice',
 parent: 'Category ID or Object Here',
});
```